# routerLink doesn't rendered into my Angular app, why?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-routerlink

I am working on an Angular application trying to introducing routing.

Into my **app.component.html** page I have this:

```
<h1>My cool app</h1>
<a routerLink="/"></a>
<a routerLink="/products"></a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

the problem is that into my page the router links are not rendered at all !!!

Routing seems to be correctly configured into my application. The **app.module.ts** file contains the **AppRoutingModule** defined into the imports:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProductsComponent,
    ProductComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [ProductsService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and this is the **app.routing.module.ts** file content:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I try to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anchor need something to anchor on

```
<a routerLink="/">Home</a>
<a routerLink="/products">Products</a>
```

Comment: Example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9cg9pw?file=src/app/app.component.html).